# How to use consul to manage different type of servers

Tags: consul

I want to register servers of different project on one consul server. 
Do we have a method to filter `consul members` on basis of their "type" or "project"? How do I segregate or filter the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should setup you consul servers: at least change default [ports](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#dns_port).
2. For `cli` commands you can specify [`-http-addr`](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/index.html). So, for example, with default settings `consul members` is the same as `consul members -http-addr=http://127.0.0.1:8500`.

Comment: Suppose I have list of servers in which 5 servers are of type-A and 5 servers are of type-B, how will `http-addr` help me filter servers of type-A ?

Comment: You have 2 clusters, each one listening on own ports and have different address.

Comment: Yes this may work in case of cluster, but if I have a technology stack with different kinds of VMs, what in that case? Can I add tags like we do in AWS?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra not sure about `cli`, but you can use tags if you have configured the dns https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html